# haskell data definition error - Illegal literal in type (use -XDataKinds to enable)

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell. when I tried:

```
Prelude> data Binary = 0 | 1
```

I got:

```
<interactive>:2:15:
    Illegal literal in type (use -XDataKinds to enable): 0
```

Even when I start ghci using `ghci -XDataKinds`

I still got:

```
<interactive>:2:15:
    parse error in constructor in data/newtype declaration: 0
```

Any one can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data Binary = 0 | 1` isn't the normal form of defining a data type. `data` definitions require data *constructors*, and `0` and `1` aren't legal syntax for them, since they're already taken for numerical literals. This is what the second error message is trying to tell you, and is basic Haskell.  The most common syntax for a data constructor is a capitalized word, so you probably want something more like

```
data Binary = Zero | One
```

NOTE: The rest of this message is advanced stuff that you will probably not need yet, but I felt like explaining a bit about why you got the *first* error message about `-XDataKinds`.

With the `DataKinds` extension, `0` and `1` *do* become legal "types" of a different kind (called `Nat`, and indeed "kind" is a technical term here), used for advanced type-level programming, and with a few more extensions it *is* possible to get a data definition containing them.

Note that the below example is probably not really *useful*, I just cobbled it together to show it is possible.  In practice unless you are doing quite advanced stuff, `data Binary = Zero | One` is probably more like what you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)

data Proxy (n :: Nat) = Proxy
data WeirdBinary = Zero (Proxy 0) | One (Proxy 1)
```

What I haven't actually been able to make work (although I've only tried for a short while) is anything starting with `data Binary = 0`. The closest I got was something weird like

```
class (n :: Nat) /// a where

data Binary = (0 /// Bool) => ThisIsSilly
```

where the `0` still needs to be inside parentheses.  I think logically this particular form *should* work without parentheses, but it doesn't.

Given this, I think Haskell is being unnecessarily confusing by suggesting that there is some way to enable extensions to fit `0` in that spot.  However, with the way parsing and type/kind checking are separate phases in GHC, it may be too complicated to catch this in a more user-friendly way, and it might even end up meaning something valid in the future.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you're not allowed to use numbers like 0 and 1 as names for the data constructors for a user defined type.  Syntactically, they have to be words that start with a capital letter.  For example, you could do this instead:

```
data Binary = O | I
```

(Note that those are the capital letters 'o' and 'i', not the digits zero and one.)

Answer (score 3):

The first error is saying that literal values like `0` and `1` (or indeed `"foo"`, `[1, 2, 3]`, `'Z'`) are not valid in a type declaration ***at all***.

You can't declare a new type that contains elements of an existing type, as it looks like you were trying with `data Binday = 0 | 1`. Types can only contain *all* of the members of another type (which is why you include other *types* in type expressions, not *values*).

The `DataKinds` extension introduces new forms of type (which I won't get into here), which mean that literal values can appear in type declarations in *some* positions. So it does resolve "Illegal literal in type" error, but even with `DataKinds` a literal value still isn't allowed in *that* position.

The second error is telling you that the compiler failed to parse "0" as a constructor name. Constructors must start with an upper case letter<sup>1</sup>, which `0` obviously does not.

I lied earlier when I said "Types can only contain *all* of the members of another type". Actually new types cannot contain *any* members of an existing type; they contain brand new values that are not members of any existing type. This is achieved by requiring all the values of the new type to be tagged by a *constructor*; the possible constructors are declared in the `data` statement, and it's the place where a constructor that must be found where you've written `0` and `1`.

`0` is already a member of the existing type `Int`<sup>2</sup>, so it can never be a member of your new type `Binary` no matter how you declare it.

You can get a `0` that is *contained within* a value of type `Binary`: `ConstructorName 0`, perhaps. But then you would have had to declare the `Binary` type as `data Binary = ConstructorName Int | ...`; after the constructor name in the type declaration should come types which identify the type of values that can be placed in that "slot" of your new `Binary` values. There is *also* no way to make that "slot" be only able to contain a `0` or a `1`, it must be an *entire* type.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or a colon for constructors that are infix operators, but that's not relevant here.

<sup>2</sup> Actually the literal expression `0` is overloaded, so it could be representing the zero element of any numeric type, but the one I'm talking about is the `Int` one.